# How to run powershell command in remote desktop from local machine using Java?

Tags: java, powershell, remote-desktop

Actually in remote desktop machine, multiple tasks are scheduled in Task Scheduler.

I have to get task information from task scheduler. Below one is powershell command and return task info.

**Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "updateDate" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo**

**I want to execute it using java in remote desktop from my local.
Remote desktop is my client's desktop so i can't install java on it.
That's why I am trying it from my local desktop.**

I am trying multiple options since many days but unable to do it.

I have remote desktop name, username and password everything.

**Please help.**

Comment: I'll let the Windows people deal with this, but my first thought: if it's a reasonably recent OS - enable Ssh server and invoke Powershell through that

Comment: You can combine that with a Java SSH API such as Jsch

Comment: Assuming proper permissions, with correct remoting configs on both systems, you could either use `Invoke-Command` or, pass a cim session to `Get-ScheduleTaskInfo`.